# function not integrable if the asymptotics of the volume of upper level sets is $\Omega(r^{-1})$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: K \subset \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function on a compact $K$. I have encountered the following statement: $\int_K f = \infty$ if  $\mathrm{vol}(\{ x\in K \mid f(x) \geq r\}) = \Omega(r^{-1})$ as $r \to \infty$. It is trivial for $n=1$ but I am at a loss how to approach it for $n > 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a relationship between the integral of a function and its distribution function i.e. superset measures. Namely for a nonnegative function $f(x)$ we have
$$\int_K f(x) = \int_0^{\infty}\mathrm{vol}(\{ x\in K \mid f(x) \geq r\})\,dr$$
I'll assume your function is nonnegative since otherwise you have counterexamples like $f(x) = {1 \over x}$ on $[-1,1]$.

Anyhow, suppose there's a constant $c > 0$ and $r_i \rightarrow \infty$ for which $\mathrm{vol}(\{ x\in K \mid f(x) \geq r_i\}) \geq c{1 \over r_i}$. By passing to a subsequence you can assume $r_{i+1} > 2r_i$ for each $i$.

In this situation the portion of the integral between $r_i$ and an $r_{i+1}$ is at least 
$(r_{i+1} - r_i) \times \mathrm{vol}(\{ x\in K \mid f(x) \geq r_{i+1}\})$, which is at least ${c \over 2}$. Adding over all $i$ gives that the integral is $\infty$.